# How to build web api in 4.5 .net framework version?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, compilation, .net-framework-version

I am trying to build WebApi app that can be hosted environment with 4.5 .net framework.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 (15.4.4 version), created empty web app project with Web Api core libraries. By default it created for 4.6 .net framework.

I changed project's target framework to 4.5, deleted and reinstalled all packages (they all are now showing as targetFramework="net45" in packages.config).

When it is deployed to environment that has only 4.5 .net framework, it fails compile with following error:

> Compilation Error    Description: An error occurred during the
>   compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please
>   review the following specific error details and modify your source
>   code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code
>   -2146232576.
>
> Show Detailed Compiler Output:
>
> c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>F:\myWebApiApp\bin\roslyn\csc.exe
>   /t:library /utf8output /nostdlib+
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\08012382\a302a9b2\assembly\dl3\fb9d2cbc\0044d876_ee54d201\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\08012382\a302a9b2\assembly\dl3\b709b96c\2cb112e8_3b95d301\myWebApiAppSvc.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\08012382\a302a9b2\assembly\dl3\ae5ab688\009d8143_af3ad001\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\08012382\a302a9b2\assembly\dl3\fa0decfa\00523e3f_5aafcf01\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\08012382\a302a9b2\assembly\dl3\f7a56ccd\003da769_af3ad001\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\08012382\a302a9b2\assembly\dl3\2996b4ac\00aba84a_af3ad001\System.Web.Http.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll"
>   /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files\root\08012382\a302a9b2\App_global.asax.ne6nua60.dll"
>   /debug- /optimize+ /warnaserror- /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618
>   /langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701 
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\08012382\a302a9b2\App_global.asax.ne6nua60.0.cs"
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\08012382\a302a9b2\App_global.asax.ne6nua60.1.cs"
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.36415

In Event Viewer it displays:

> .NET Runtime version : 4.0.30319.36415 - This application could not be
>   started.This application requires one of the following versions of the
>   .NET Framework:  .NETFramework,Version=v4.6
>
> Do you want to install this .NET Framework version now?

Did I miss something? How I can find out what exactly depends on 4.6? Perhaps there is easier way to create WebApi app in 4.5 .net framework?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify desired .net framework version when you creating your project.

[image]